# How can I make a CameraSelector build class in Jetpack Compose remember to avoid recomposition issue?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a build class in Kotlin compose i want to make it remember for avoiding some recompositions issues

```
val cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer

```
val cameraSelector = remember {
    CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        .build()
}
```